# How do you download online libraries on python?

Tags: python

I am trying to download youtube videos using python and for the code to work I need to install pytube3 library but I am very new to coding so I am not sure how to do it.

Comment: Checkout youtube-dl ; Note you shouldn't actually be downloading the videos; Be-aware of licensing issues.. `pip install <your_lib_name>`

Comment: I suggest reading [realpython.com pip tutorial](https://realpython.com/what-is-pip/)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use pip:

```
pip install pytube3
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use

`python3 -m pip install pytube3`

Answer (score 1):

Use sign of exclamation at the start of command.
Like this:

```
!pip install pytube3
```